# Extracting text embedded within <td> under some class

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[Table from data to be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oksq7.png)Extract text within  under specific class and store in respective lists

I am trying to extract data from "https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/vietjetair/page/1/" . I am able to extract the summary, review and user info, but unable to get the tabular data. Tabular data needs to be stored in respective lists. Different user reviews have different number of ratings. Given in the code below are couple of things which I tried. All are giving empty lists. 
Extracted review using xpath

```
(review = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="tc_mobile"]//div[@class="text_content "]') )
```

following are some xpaths which are giving empty list. Here I m=am trying to extract data/text corresponding to "Type Of Traveller "

```
tot = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="tc_mobile active"]//div[@class="review-stats"]//table[@class="review-ratings"]//tbody//tr//td[@class="review-rating-header type_of_traveller "]//td[@class="review-value "]')

tot1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="tc_mobile"]//div[@class="review-stats"]//table//tbody//tr//td[@class="review-rating-header type_of_traveller "]//td[@class="review-value "]')


tot2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div//div/table//tbody//tr//td[@class="review-rating-header type_of_traveller "]//td[@class = "review-value "]')
```

Comment: Please let us know exactly which elements are you trying to automating by pointing out in screenshot that will be better because i have tried with first xpath and not able find it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want. All the code is doing at a basic level is following the DOM structure and then iterating over each element at that layer.

It extracts the values into a dictionary for each review and then appends that to a results list:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/vietjetair/page/1/")
review_tables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="tc_mobile"]//table[@class="review-ratings"]//tbody')  # Gets all the review tables

results = list()  # A list of all rating results
for review_table in review_tables:
    review_rows = review_table.find_elements_by_xpath('./tr')  # Gets each row from the table
    rating = dict()  # Holds the rating result
    for row in review_rows:
        review_elements = row.find_elements_by_xpath('./td')  # Gets each element from the row
        if review_elements[1].text == '12345':  # Logic to extract star rating as int
            rating[review_elements[0].text] = len(review_elements[1].find_elements_by_xpath('./span[@class="star fill"]'))
        else:
            rating[review_elements[0].text] = review_elements[1].text
    results.append(rating)  # Add rating to results list
```

**Sample entry of review data in results list:**

> {
>       "Date Flown": "January 2019",
>       "Value For Money": 2,
>       "Cabin Staff Service": 3,
>       "Route": "Ho Chi Minh City to Bangkok",
>       "Type Of Traveller": "Business",
>       "Recommended": "no",
>       "Seat Comfort": 3,
>       "Cabin Flown": "Economy Class",
>       "Ground Service": 1
>   }